# How to Create a Data Access Layer in ASP.Net which must be generic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, data-access-layer

I have looked several sites CodeProject,CSharpCorner,MSDN,CSharpPearls etc including one StackOverflow link:-

[how to create single Data Access Layer to access two different data source in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714345/how-to-create-single-data-access-layer-to-access-two-different-data-source-in-as)

But I was dissatisfied with the answer.

I want to create a DAL for my website in ASP.net C#, where I am using Web.Config to get ConnectionString. But the thing is suppose today Im connecting to SQLSERVER, my DAL is capable to connect to SQLSERVER. But suppose in future Im adding one more connectionString and now Connecting to SQLSERVER with one connection string and MYSQL with another, My DAL must be capable to connect to all type of database without problem.

What I did till now is for SQLServer which is working for SQLServer but I want this to be generic and working for OLEDB,MYSQL, SQLCLIENT, (BIGTABLE & CASANDRA IF POSSIBLE) and all other providers.

Here is my what i tried till now :-

```
namespace MyDAL
{
namespace DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    /// <summary>
    /// BaseDataManager is used to connect to database
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable()]
    public class BaseDataManager : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposedValue = false;
        private SqlConnection _connectionObject = null;
        private SqlCommand _commandObject = null;
        public BaseDataManager()
        { }
        /// <summary>
        /// Provide ConnectionString
        /// </summary>
        public BaseDataManager(string connectionString)
        {
            this.SqlConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// if config is true provide connectionstring name in Web.config
        /// else if config is false provide connectionstring rather than providing                     
        ///name
        /// </summary>
        public BaseDataManager(String connectionString_Name, Boolean config)
        {
            if (config == true)
            {
                this.SqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionString_Name].ConnectionString;
            }
            else if (config == false)
            {
                this.SqlConnectionString = connectionString_Name;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error in Connection String, Check Web.Config ");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Provide data source=; as connection string, username and password of
        /// database 
        /// </summary>
        public BaseDataManager(string DataSource, string InitialCatalog, bool IntegratedSecurity)
        {
            if (IntegratedSecurity == true)
            {
                this.SqlConnectionString += "Data Source=" + DataSource + "InitialCatalog=" + InitialCatalog + ";Integrated Security=" + IntegratedSecurity;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provide data source=; as connection string, username and password of
        /// database 
        /// </summary>
        public BaseDataManager(string DataSource,string InitialCatalog, string username, string password)
        {
            this.SqlConnectionString += "Data Source="+DataSource+"InitialCatalog="+InitialCatalog+";User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password;
        }

        public string SqlConnectionString
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual SqlConnection connection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_connectionObject == null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty (this.SqlConnectionString))
                    _connectionObject = new SqlConnection (this.SqlConnectionString);
                return _connectionObject;
            }
            set
            {
                _connectionObject = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual SqlCommand command
        {
            get
            {
                if (_commandObject == null)
                    _commandObject = new SqlCommand();
                return _commandObject;
            }
            set
            {
                _commandObject = value;
            }
        }

        public SqlConnection getOpenConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            return connection;
        }

        public SqlCommand getCommand()
        {
            return command;
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {


   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // Close the connection object prior to setting it to nothing


   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    if (_connectionObject != null)
                    {
                        _connectionObject.Close();
                        _connectionObject.Dispose();
                    }
                    if (_commandObject != null)
                    {
                        _commandObject.Cancel();
                        _commandObject.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                _disposedValue = true;
            }
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    GC.Collect();
        }

        ~BaseDataManager()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

    }
 }
 }
```

Please Help Me..

Comment: Raj the answer in the link that you provided tells you what you need to do `The key is to make sure that your other code, uses an interface, not an implementation, to access your DAL.` what seems to be your issue..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have created interface for the service class and not for the BaseDataManager.My interface is:-                                                 `namespace MyDAL
{
    namespace DB
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        public interface DAO
        {
            int I_U_D_Data(String query);
            SqlDataReader read_Data(String query);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: What about using Entity Framework, which can be used with many different databases.

Comment: @JohnSaunders No I cant use Entity Framework since my juniors are not aware about it. I need to use ADO.NET wih DAL only

Comment: FYI, EF is "ADO.NET Entity Framework". Also, it's been out for four years or more - probably time your juniors were only two years out of date.

Comment: Please I need this, someone please answer... I dont need Entity FW. Simple ADO with DAL. Its 49 views and still no positive response..

Comment: Anyone please reply I need this to be solved...
Moreover I cant post now what I tried as Moderator has blocked me. Can anyone tell did i violated any community rights??

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen work is to provide Data Access Objects (DAOs) on a per entity basis - not one gigantic DAO.

I'd keep it really simple and not make too many abstractions.  Let's say you're doing an application about schools.  Some entities:

- School
- Teacher
- Student

Then you can make interfaces for each DAO:

- ISchoolDAO
- ITeacherDAO
- IStudentDAO

Each DAO has functions that are specific to you application.  I wouldn't recommend trying to make it to generic.  You might have methods like this for School:

- public List GetSchools()
- public School GetSchool(int id)

Then when you implement the interface for the DAO it can be whatever technology you want.  Remember that things like BigTable/Hadoop/SQL do *not* conform to the same concepts.  One is a relational database and another is not relational.

Use the interfaces throughout your code and then you can write unit tests and easily swap out the underlying technology.

(Worth repeating ... don't try to read in SQL statements as part of the interfaces.  Remember those don't map across technologies the same.)

Comment: But i want to make one main DAL for my entire network for connection. Moreover what you are saying can go in extension of my DAL so that creating specific functions for specific work. But indeed then too we need to write everything for execution on db,so i want to make it in such a way that my juniors just create reference of my functions and need not to bother about connection or objects related to it. Then they wil create a collection where they will be puting everything back to UI. And I dont think it cant be made. Infact I have made half portion and will post in few daz. Thanks nywaz

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reply perfectly, but the original post had two big requirements: 1) A data access layer to abstract away the database 2) Ability to swap in/out different technologies.  You realize that when you write a function that takes a SQL connection string, you have limited your ability to do (2). If you want a DAL that can swap out _only_ databases like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, then your original proposal could work.

Comment: Still in my original post it lacks Generic Behaviour and I cant use any other database directly. So atleast suggest me a generic code